# Need to repeat the result rows based on a column value

Tags: sql-server

I need a help in generating SQL result based on a column value to calculate per day amount.

I have a SQL like below.

```
select guid, reccharge, dayCareDaysCharged, dayCareHoursPerDay, RATE from tableA.
```

Here if reccharge = 0 (weekly) then the result should have 7 rows with RATE as RATE/7 for each row (per day amount);
if reccharge = 1 (monthly) then the result should have 30 rows with RATE as RATE/30 for each row;
if reccharge = 2 (yearly) then the result should have 365 rows with RATE as RATE/365 for each row;
if reccharge = 3 (hourly) then there should be a row as calculate it for a day;

How can I achieve this. Please help.

Comment: What is the data type of `reccharge`? At first I assumed it was numeric, with a value of `0` and `(weekly)` was your comment about that value - but then you give a monthly example where it's also equal to 0? So is it's value (in your first example) `0` or `0 (weekly)`?

Comment: am sorry. For monthly the value is 1. Mistakenly I put it as 0. The datatype is numeric.

Comment: You can edit your question - I'd recommend you do that now to correct the example - there's an edit link just below the tags.

Comment: Do you really want to use 30 as the basis for days in month, or would you be more interested in the actual number of days per month? IE, Feb would have 28 days,where Jan would have 31.

Comment: If I can get the actual number of day then it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have not idea to do it in single query, but you can do it by using CURSOR as like below :

```
declare @reccharge int
declare @count int
declare @i int
declare @strSQL nvarchar(max) = 'select 1, 1 where 1 <> 1'

declare CurTest cursor for select reccharge from test

open CurTest
fetch next from CurTest into @reccharge

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @i = 0; 

    select @count = case when @reccharge = 0 then 7 when @reccharge = 1 then 30 when @reccharge = 2 then 365 else 1 end

    while @i < @count 
    begin 
        set @strSQL = @strSQL + ' union all select reccharge, Rate/' + cast(@count as varchar(10)) + ' from test where reccharge = ' + cast(@reccharge as varchar(10))
        set @i = @i + 1; 
    end

fetch next from CurTest into @reccharge
end

close CurTest
deallocate CurTest

exec(@strSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a little strange to me, but if I've followed it correctly then maybe this;

```
    CREATE TABLE [#temp1] (reccharge tinyint,rdays smallint)
    GO
    declare @rcount smallint
    set @rcount=0
    while @rcount<7
    begin
    set @rcount=@rcount+1
    insert #temp1 values (0,7)
    end
    set @rcount=0
    while @rcount<30
    begin
    set @rcount=@rcount+1
    insert #temp1 values (1,30)
    end
    set @rcount=0
    while @rcount<365
    begin
    set @rcount=@rcount+1
    insert #temp1 values (2,365)
    end
    insert #temp1 values (3,1)
    GO

    select t1.[guid], t1.reccharge, t1.dayCareDaysCharged, t1.dayCareHoursPerDay, t1.RATE/t2.rdays as RATE from tableA t1
    inner join #temp1 t2 on t1.reccharge=t2.reccharge
    order by t1.[guid]
```